# PHP MySQL Foreach loop on Fetch_Array

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am working to build a management system to manage user bets (on sports games). There is a lot that goes into this, but knowing this will make explaining my question a little easier to understand.

I want to keep track of each individual user bet in a table similar to the following:

```
User Name   Date    Betting Site    Parlay ID   Home Team   Away Team   Wager   Odds    Bet Info    Success
Ridge R     3/1/16  Bet365          1           Chelsea     Man City    1000    2.0     Home Win    Yes
Ridge R     3/2/16  Bet365          1           Barcelona   Real Madrid 400     1.7     Home Win    Yes
John D      3/4/16  William Hill    2           Wigan       Newcastle   2100    1.4     Home Win    No
```

I would get this info from our DB through joining a couple tables. We have many users, betting sites and obviously games that can be bet on. This table is then created from a while loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
          $output = '<tr>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$row['First Name'].' '.$row['Last Name'].'</td>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$row['Game Date'].'</td>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$row['Betting Site Name'].'</td>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$row['Parlay ID'].'</td>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$row['Home Team'].'</td>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$row['Away Team'].'</td>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$row['Wager'].' kr</td>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$row['Odds'].'</td>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$row['Bet Info'].'</td>';
          $output .= '<td>'.$row['Success'].'</td>';
          $output .= '</tr>';

          echo $output;
}
```

What I am having trouble with is this:

How can I join each bet record into the same  where each of the parlay id's are the same? The reason I am asking is because I stripe my table by every other row with different color, but I need all games that are part of a parlay to be the same color.

I tried something similar to...

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $output = '<tr>';
    ...
    foreach ($row['Parlay ID'] as **COULDN'T FIGURE OUT THIS PART**) {
        $output .= '<table><tr>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$row['First Name' ].' '.$row['Last Name'].'</td>';
        $output .= '</tr></table>';            
        .......
    }
THEN CONTINUE TABLE FOR OTHER ONES
}
```

I know this is a pretty poor attempt, but I hope it gives across the idea I am going for! Perhaps a foreach loop is not each the right idea...any ideas on how this can work?

Comment: Do you need nested tables or do you only need the rows with the same Parlay IDs to have the same background color?

Comment: I think a nested table is better...but perhaps just using CSS on a parlay ID number could suffice. Either way, I'm not sure how I can get the right class to show based on only parlayID's being equal to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want same rows to share the same color you could:

```
$colors = array("red", "blue");
$lastParlayID = false; $lastColor = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      if ($row["Parlay ID"] !== $lastParlayID) {
          $lastParlayID = $row["Parlay ID"];
          ++$lastColor;
      }
      if ($lastColor >= count($colors)) $lastColor=0;
      $output = '<tr style="background:'.$colors[$lastColor].'>';
      $output .= '<td>'.$row['First Name'].' '.$row['Last Name'].'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'.$row['Game Date'].'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'.$row['Betting Site Name'].'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'.$row['Parlay ID'].'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'.$row['Home Team'].'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'.$row['Away Team'].'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'.$row['Wager'].' kr</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'.$row['Odds'].'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'.$row['Bet Info'].'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'.$row['Success'].'</td>';
      $output .= '</tr>';
      echo $output;
}
```

You can also replace the $colors with CSS classes and do class= instead of style=.

Comment: I can go for this idea...I think this may work. I have implemented and modified the colors to be just "#f9f9f9" and "#ffffff", although I will end up using CSS classes so I can modify the <td>'s inside them as well....but one problem is that this will only work for the first two rows (since I only listed two colors in the colors array). How can I get the colors array to repeat itself?

Comment: I added another conditional block. There, if the value of $lastColor is equal or grater than the amount of colors indicated, it resets the cursor to 0 (the first element in the $colors array). This happens already at the beginning, since $lastColor is now initialized to 1 and at the first iteration it gets incremented by 1.

Comment: alright...this has worked. Originally I wasn't considering doing it this way, but I can't see why this would be a problem for my needs! Thanks for the solution